Linux Azure Webjob in nodejs referring to node.exe
I tried to switch to preview Azure App Service Webjobs running on linux for nodejs continuous webjob without luck.
(I have deep successful experiences on nodejs/C# ones on AppService Webjobs running on windows).
The beginning is promising, but for unclear reason, the error message refers to node.exe
[09/24/2024 19:24:02 > 6843e9: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton lock is acquired
[09/24/2024 19:24:02 > 6843e9: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.js' with script host - 'NodeScriptHost'
[09/24/2024 19:24:02 > 6843e9: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[09/24/2024 19:24:02 > 6843e9: ERR ] An error occurred trying to start process 'node.exe' with working directory '/home/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/test3'. No such file or directory
[09/24/2024 19:24:02 > 6843e9: SYS ERR ] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred trying to start process 'node.exe' with working directory '/home/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/test3'. No such file or directory)
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process 'node.exe' with working directory '/home/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/test3'. No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Tried to play with an extra "script.sh" inspired from this site with no success.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/create-and-deploy-linux-webjobs-on-azure-app-service/ba-p/4218587
#!/bin/bash
node run.js

stack correctly on nodejs 20
enabled SCM Basic Auth

worth noting, the script runs fine if directly instancied from ssh within the appservice (xxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/webssh)

Tried deployment via

ftp
zip deployment
directly playing through ssh/vi/etc

run.js (simplied a bit ;))
console.log("I'm alive");

script.sh
#!/bin/bash
/opt/node-wrapper/node run.js


How did you deploy the WebJob via FTP, Azure cli ,zip deployment

Can you share the contents of run.js and script.sh

I added information at the bottom

by renaming script.sh to run.sh, it worked but it seems using  script host - 'BashScriptHost' rather 'NodeScriptHost'. Not sure if it has a strong impact.

I created a sample Node.js WebJob script, zipped the script file, and uploaded it to Azure WebJobs.


ERR ] An error occurred trying to start process 'node.exe' with working directory '/home/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/test3'. No such file or directory

The above error occurred because of naming convention in web jobs.

When you name the file run.js, the WebJob considers it as an entry point, and it can cause errors.
I got the same error when I used file name as run.js, so to avoid the error I've changed file name  run.js to any other name like index.js or server.js.
As mentioned in comment, if you want to use the file name run.js, then you should also change the .sh file name to run.sh to ensure it works correctly.

My script .sh:
node run.js

I can successfully see the Azure web job logs without any errors.


came up with the same solution, still not sure if there is an actual big difference between BashScriptHost and NodeScriptHost.

When you use run.js, WebJobs thinks it's a special Node.js script and tries to run it using NodeScriptHost, which can cause issues. Renaming it to index.js makes WebJobs use BashScriptHost instead, which runs the script more smoothly and avoids the error
